# what is the purpose of number >>> 0 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Found this line in [Array.protoype.find polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on MDN

```
var len = o.length >>> 0;
```

what is the purpose of this line? it seems that it return same value as length.

The comment say:

```
// 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
```

what it mean? Is to convert lenght to a number using coercion?

Comment: it is an integer casting with bitshifting.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29